# Is it possible to call this file from a command button

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

im having a bit of issues calling a java file, i have created a java file

```
   @ManagedBean(name="pdfSearch")

public class pdfSearch {

    public String NewDestination;

    public void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        File dir = new File(NewDestination);
        String[] extensions = new String[]{"pdf"};// Add more file formats here to disply, could use this later on to display to the user all the files they have uploaded
        System.out.println("Getting all .pdf files");
        List<File> files = (List<File>) FileUtils.listFiles(dir, extensions, true);
        for (File file : files) {
            System.out.println(file.getCanonicalPath());
        }

    }
}
```

But i can not call this to run from a command button

```
                <p:commandButton action="#{pdfSearch.main}" value="Search"  ajax="False"/>
```

Comment: What is expected behavior?

Comment: Wich JSF implementation are you using?

Comment: JSF 2.1, And it is expected when the user presses the button in the console it displays all the pdf files in the users directory, this is currently just for testing before i add further features

Comment: You really should think about those annotations on `Filter` class. Two of them are unnecessary. `@SessionScoped` vs `@ViewScoped` and `@Named` vs `@ManagedBean`

Comment: Ok so i have re done my code, but am still un able to call from a command button

Answer (score 1):

The filter.finder method is not a JSF Action method.  That is meant to be a method of the signature

public String methodName()

That won't work in stock-standard JSF.  I'd brush up on the JSF documentation for action methods.

Comment: I have since re done my code but i still get the same issue, any advice on what i am doing wrong

Comment: Please find some documentation which discusses Actions vs ActionListeners.  The default method signature for a command button's action attribute is a ManagedBean's method which takes no arguments and returns a String (which can be used for page navigation)

Comment: You can also used the actionListener attribute instead.  If you use that attribute, the method signature returns a null and takes a single input parameter of type ActionEvent.  The signature of the method you are trying to call from the commandButton attribute is incorrect (both iterations of them).

Comment: Professor Google can return plenty of examples "JSF Action"... try http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-form-action-navigation-rule-example/ or  http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=605 or dozens of existing questions on StackOverflow already

Answer (score 0):

Also you have written that you could use `.toLowerCase()`, if you wanted to search for files that are lowercase only. But this is not the case.

It will just make it see the letters as all lower case if you then wanted to order in them in lexiographical order for example.